# @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) and @AutoConfigureMockMvc at the same time seems to be an anti-pattern

Tags: mocking, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I am currently studying the usage of these two annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

I saw a code base which looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class LoginEndToEndTest {

   @Autowired protected MockMvc mvc;
```

isn't it an bad/anti pattern?

In fact,

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

seems to be used to launch a real embedded servlet container,
while @AutoConfigureMockMvc is used to make... mocks!

So, are these 2 annotations are compatible at the same time?

thanks.